# What is the wallpaper tag used for?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I just want to know why there is a [wallpaper](/questions/tagged/wallpaper) tag on Stack Overflow. It's a programming Q&A site and I don't think it has anything to do with wallpapers. So what's the use of it?

Also using it will create off-topic questions, won't it?

Comment: for making the walls around your Windows look nice...

Comment: The presence of a tag will not *create* off-topic questions. You are not justified in asking obviously off-topic questions just because you found a tag with a meaning that you can twist and contort. All of the tags on Stack Overflow can be thought of as having an implicit `-programming` ending. So, a wallpaper tag can be used for programming questions that have to do with changing/editing desktop wallpaper.

Comment: ah, the perks of being a wallpaper...

Answer (score 2):

There are many legitimate questions one might ask about wallpapers that are on-topic for Stack Overflow. Looking through the [list of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wallpaper), most of them seem on-topic.

The majority seem to relate to resizing issues and/or how to adjust the wallpaper image using code. Nothing wrong with that!

Answer (score 1):

From the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wallpaper):

> Wallpaper is the background image on one's "desktop" or "home screen."

I'm pretty sure it's not there for the sticky paper kind :) Probably more important in the mobile development stuff, but there's no reason a question couldn't be about doing something with the wallpaper (be it on a PC or mobile device).